# How is the neck of the green velociraptor 10757 connected?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I found a green velociraptor in a box on the curb, presumably from the "rescue truck" 10757 box. The head is detached from the body and there is no obvious way to attach it.

I found a light sabre handle that fits as a "neck", as would a basic round pin (on one end).

I can't find what the proper connector is. From official images of the box it looks like it must be a type of stick that is virtually invisible.

I'd appreciate any suggestions to connect the head correcttly.

PS. I may not know the right terminology I don't claim to be a lego expert by any stretch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at [inventory for Velociraptor](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?P=Raptor08), included in 10757 set you've mentioned, there is a Technic Pin. Since all of the limbs have half of the pin molded into the parts this leaves us with Technic Pin that is used to connect body with a head piece.

[image]

Better pictured by this step from LEGO building instruction (thanks Syberion for the tip):

[image]

Comment: Correct, this can also be seen in the [instructions](https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/6238343.pdf) on page 8